# Empty Django Inline saying fields are required

Tags: django, admin, inline

In django admin I'm trying to create a new entry, but fields in the inline forms are throwing errors saying they are required even if I don't want to create a new inline.

models:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(choices=ATTRIBUTE_CHOICES, max_length=max_choice_len(ATTRIBUTE_CHOICES))
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {str(self.amount)}'

class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    attributes = GenericRelation(Attribute)
```

admin:

```
class AttributeInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Attribute
    extra = 0

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AttributeInline]
    class Meta:
        model = Item

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```